# How can I conditionally disable left-shift key

Tags: arch-linux

Over the past year, I've gained a lot from practicing touch-typing. I hope it can be brought to the next level. A way seems productive to me is to use the right shift key to capitalize characters on the left side of the keyboards. I find it hard to change this >15-yo bad habit, but reckon that there might be some way to force me to do it remapping keys.

Is there a way to disable `Left_Shift + *`, where * is the following: `q,a,z,w,s,x,e,d,c,r,f,v,t,g,b` on linux?

Answer (score 1):

To do it you could use `xmodmap`  in similar way as described in
https://superuser.com/questions/483088/how-can-i-map-the-left-and-right-shift-key-individually